# Video footage as a material?

Tags: materials, video

I've been learning how to make planet from this course: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3g8XxmqSP90. Planets textures are used as materials over the surface of a sphere but I wanted to know. Is it possible to use moving video footage as a material on a sphere?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a video as texture the same way you would use any other image texure[image]